# Connect PostgreSQL to Java Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I'm trying to make my java dynamic web project work with postgresql database, but cannot figure out how to do that correctly.

What I did:

1. create Dynamic Web Project that runs on Tomcat v8.0
2. download postgresql jdbc driver
3. throw the `postgresql-9.4-1205.jdbc4.jar` file into my `WEB-INF/lib`
   folder
4. create database `java_lab2`, create user `lab2` with password `qwerty`, grant all privileges to user `lab2` and create table `users`, all in psql
5. create `META-INF/context.xml` file
6. modify `WEB-INF/web.xml` file

---

here's my context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/connectorDs" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="lab2" password="qwerty"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/java_lab2"
        maxTotal="10" maxIdle="4" />

</Context>
```

here's what I've added to `web.xml`:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>PostgreSQL data source</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/connectorDs</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

---

and now I cannot figure out how to actually start working with the database.

How do I connect to it? How do I query it in my servlets after the connection?

## Update

I added the following function to my servlet:

```
private void attemptConnection() {
    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                + "Include in your library path!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/java_lab2", "lab2",
                "qwerty");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}
```

and run it in `doGet` method.

This gives me the following output:

> PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!
>
> Connection Failed! Check output console
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt
>   failed.   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>
> ......................
>   ......................
>
> Caused by:
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:284)   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:405)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
>     ... 35 more

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL. Also, localhost:8080 is the address of the Tomcat web server. PostgreSQL runs, by default, on port 5432 (es shown in the documentation).

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, the port was the problem, I had to change it in my function as well as in context.xml. could you post this as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: JB Nizet is right, you need to specify the port *Postgres* listens on, not the Tomcat port. Also: if you have defined a JNDI datasource you don't need (and you shouldn't use) `DriverManager.getConnection()`. See the JDBC tutorial for examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Comment: @DenisYakovenko read the documentation. The port is not the main problem: you define a connection pool in Tomcat, but without providing the driver to tomcat, and you're not using that pool anyway in the code: using DriverManager creates a brand new connection every time. Just follow the instructions in the doc. That's what it's for.